# Re-scale axis when zoomed

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, charts

I'm creating a similar graph to this:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

However when I'm zooming in to a certain section, I would like to scale the Y axis to the local (displayed) maximum, instead of the global one. For example when I zoom to the data between 2009 and 2010 there is a lot of empty white space at the top.

Basically what I would like to achieve is get the range to which I've zoomed, and get the maximum value within that.

The other possibility would be adding another brush bar on the side, but that would be very inconvenient on the long run for the users.

Comment: This is a duplicate for v3, and in my opinion for v4 as well (since the changes in the scales' names are minimal). However, to avoid arguments, I wrote you an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `y` scale domain for that.

First, let's create a global variable named `globalData` and associate the data array to it. Note: this is **not** the correct way to do this, but I'll do it simply because the `brushed` and `zoomed` functions lie outside `d3.csv`, which is *asynchronous*, and refactoring it takes some work... so, it will be **your** job refactoring it.

Then, in both the `brushed` and `zoomed` functions, we filter the data according to the brush:

```
var filteredData = globalData.filter(function(d){
    return d.date > x.domain()[0] && d.date < x.domain()[1]
});
```

After that, we calculate the new y domain:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(filteredData, function(d){
    return d.price
})]);
```

Don't forget to call the axis again.

This is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/17fd6b82324e355c768992e78140fe9a/33b9a6c58265454864a9d921df032e708fad5237